# Indented code for Ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a gem that allows us to write Ruby code in Rails with indentation the way Haml and CoffeeScript do for html and javascript respectively?

Google always ends up with Lazibi but that project has been dead for 5 years.

Comment: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5054 isn't very practical, but it should bring a smile to your face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with adopting a Python-style syntax for Ruby is that Python's syntax crucially depends on the distinction between statements and expressions. For example, a lambda can only contain expressions not statements (or to put it another way: a lambda's body must consist of a single statement). Ruby, however, doesn't have statements, it only has expressions.

This means that adopting a Python-style syntax for Ruby (or any other Ruby-like language) is impossible. Tony Arcieri tried it with Reia, for example, but he had to revert his decision, precisely because of the fact that Reia, like Ruby, doesn't have statements.

A Haskell-like or F#-like syntax would probably work much better, but nobody has implemented it yet.

Comment: I don't think it's unfathomable to have something that "compiles" to Ruby by adding the chrome (do, end, whatnots), just like CoffeeScript "compiles" to Javascript by adding the chrome of stuff that just satisfies the compiler (braces, semi-colons, function, parenthesis, etc.)